# Views not refreshing correctly using SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

in my code, i have a view called "show.ejs" which shows client details. the proble; now is that if i update client details (image, associated docs, ...) the content remains the same and changes only if i refresh the page ( by F5 ) .
this my update and show  actions in ClientController :

```
findOne : function(req,res){
    Client.findOne({
        id : req.param('id')
    })
    .populate('docs')
    .populate('sites')
    .exec(function(err,client){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(client) { 
        return res.view('client/show', {
            client : client
        });
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/client');

    }
    })

},
update : function(req,res){
    var name = req.param('name'),
        id = req.param('id'),
        town = req.param('town'),
        adress = req.param('adress'),
        postalCode = req.param('postalCode'),
        telephone = req.param('telephone'),
        email = req.param('email'),
        fax = req.param('fax'),
        responsable = req.param('responsable'),
        website = req.param('website'),
        activity = req.param('activity');

    Client.findOne({id : id}).exec(function(err,client) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        client.name = name;
        client.town = town;
        client.adress = adress;
        client.telephone = telephone;
        client.fax = fax;
        client.website = website;
        client.email=email;
        client.responsable=responsable;
        client.postalCode=postalCode;
        client.activity = activity;
        client.save();
        req.file('logo').upload({
                dirname: require('path')
                        .resolve(sails.config.appPath+'/assets/uploads/clients/logos/')
                }, function (err, logo) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                if(typeof logo !== 'undefined' && logo.length > 0 ) {
                                    require('fs').unlink('./assets/uploads/clients/logos/'+client.logo, function(err){
                                            if(err) console.log(err)
                                            client.logo = require('path').basename(logo[0].fd);
                                            client.save();
                                                    })
                                }
                                return res.redirect('/client/'+client.id );
                            });
    }) 
}
```

and this is how i setup the view :

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- BEGIN PROFILE SIDEBAR -->
                        <div class="profile-sidebar" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                            <!-- PORTLET MAIN -->
                            <div class="portlet light profile-sidebar-portlet  " style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                                <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                                <div class="profile-userpic">
                                    <img src="/uploads/clients/logos/<%= client.logo %>" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="image client"> </div>
                                <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                                <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                                <div class="profile-usertitle ">
                                    <div class="profile-usertitle-name"><%= client.name %></div>
                                    <div class="profile-usertitle-job"> Client </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- END PORTLET MAIN -->
                            <!-- PORTLET MAIN -->
                            <div class="portlet light " style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                                <!-- STAT -->
                                <div class="row list-separated profile-stat">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="uppercase profile-stat-title"> <%= 44 %> </div>
                                        <div class="uppercase profile-stat-text"> Sites </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="uppercase profile-stat-title"><%= 49 %> </div>
                                        <div class="uppercase profile-stat-text"> Documents </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <!-- END STAT -->
                                <div>


                                     <div class="margin-top-20 profile-desc-link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                        <span class="profile-desc-text" ><%= client.adress %></span>
                                    </div>
                                  <div class="margin-top-20 profile-desc-link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                        <a href="#"><%= client.email %> </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="margin-top-20 profile-desc-link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                        <a href="#"><%= client.website %></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END PORTLET MAIN -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- END BEGIN PROFILE SIDEBAR -->
                        <!-- BEGIN PROFILE CONTENT -->
                        <div class="profile-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="portlet light ">
                                        <div class="portlet-title tabbable-line">
                                            <div class="caption caption-md">
                                                <i class="icon-globe theme-font hide"></i>
                                                <span class="caption-subject font-blue-madison bold uppercase">Client N° <strong> <%= client.id %></strong></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                <li class="active">
                                                    <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">informations</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">Documents</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">Sites</a>
                                                </li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="portlet-body">
                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <!-- PERSONAL INFO TAB -->
                                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
                                                      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="edit">
                                                         <div class="form-actions">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
                                                                    <input type="text" hidden name="id" value="<%=client.id%>">
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn green">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Modifier</button>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-body">
                                                      <h3 class="form-section">Informations Personneles </h3>

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">ID :</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                   <strong> <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.id %> </p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nom :</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                 <strong>   <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.name %> </p></strong> </strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--/row-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Responsable :</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                  <strong>   <p class="form-control-static"><%= client.responsable %></p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Email :</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                 <strong>    <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.email %> </p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--/row-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Téléphone :</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                  <strong>   <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.telephone %> </p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Fax :</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                  <strong>   <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.fax %> </p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--/row-->
                                                    <h3 class="form-section">Adresse</h3>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">#</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                                  <strong>   <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.adress %> </p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Ville:</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                 <strong>    <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.town %> </p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/span-->

                                                           <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-6">Code postal:</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                  <strong>   <p class="form-control-static"> <%= client.postalCode %></p></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <!--/span-->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--/row-->

                                                </div>

                                            </form>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- END PERSONAL INFO TAB -->
                                                <!-- CHANGE AVATAR TAB -->
                                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
                                                   <div class="form-actions">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn green" data-toggle="modal" href="#basic">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Ajouter un doc </button>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <!--- doc model -->

                                                     <div class="modal fade" id="basic" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                             <div class="modal-content">
                                                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                                                     <h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter un Document</h4>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                      <div class="modal-body"> 
                                                                      <form action="/client/addDocument" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                                        <input type="text" hidden name="id" value="<%= client.id %>">
                                                                        <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 22px;">
                                                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Titre</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                             <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left">
                                                                                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                                                                                 </span>
                                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-circle-right" placeholder="titre du document" name="title"> </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <br>
                                                                           <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 22px;">
                                                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                             <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left">
                                                                                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                                                                                 </span>
                                                                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-circle-right" name="description" placeholder="description du document"> </textarea>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                     <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 22px; padding-top: 40px;">
                                                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Document</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                                                         <span class="btn green btn-file">
                                                                            <span class="fileinput-new"> Selectionner Fichier </span>
                                                                            <span class="fileinput-exists"> Changer </span>
                                                                            <input type="file" name="fichier"> </span>
                                                                            <span class="fileinput-filename"> </span> &nbsp;
                                                                             <a href="javascript:;" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> </a>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>


                                                                      </div>
                                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                     <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn green">Enregistrer</button>
                                                                    </form>
                                                                 </div>
                                                            </div>
                                        <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                                        </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- fin doc model -->


                                                <br>
                                                    <div class="portlet light bordered">
                                                         <div class="portlet-title">
                                                             <div class="caption font-green">
                                                                     <i class=" fa fa-file font-green"></i>
                                                                         <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase" style="margin-right : 11px;">Liste des Documents</span> 

                                                             </div>

                                                          </div>
                                                <div class="portlet-body">
                                                 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" id="sample_1">

                                   <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="all">#</th>
                                            <th class="min-tablet">Titre</th>
                                            <th class="desktop">Description</th>
                                         <th class="all" style="width : 66px">Action.</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <% _.each(client.docs, function (doc) { %>

                                         <tr>
                                            <td ><%=doc.id%></td>
                                           <td ><%= doc.title %></td>
                                          <td ><%= doc.description %></td>
                                      <center>  <td>
                                        <a href="#" title="telecharger" class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only green" ><i class="fa fa-download" ></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" title="Supprimer" class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only purple-sharp"  data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="left" data-btn-ok-label="Continuer" data-btn-ok-icon="icon-like" data-btn-ok-class="btn-success" data-btn-cancel-label="Annuler!"
                                data-btn-cancel-icon="icon-close" data-btn-cancel-class="btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                                </td></center>

                                        </tr>

                                         <% }) %>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually following your code, the problems reside in

```
client.save()
```

which is an asynchronous function.

the problem is you are changing the client and you are not waiting for the changes to be saved to upload the logo and reload the data.

here's [the official doc](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/save), which is stating that model.save has a callback to it.

```
client.save(function(){
    /*your code */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The view, with those EJS functions is doing what is expected to do. You see, you are not providing some way to magically change data on-the-fly. Instead what EJS and your controller is doing is this: `Get all data needed - with findOne` -> `Put that data on the view - with EJS and <% %> markers` -> `Render and serve a static HTML document - res.view`.

If you need data to change on the fly you need a more powerful framework on the frontend, like Vuejs or Angular... EJS is meant to assembly a static page with dynamic data ONCE. Take a look at the docs[image: enter link description here]